# Determine if file can be deleted on windows in go

Tags: windows, go

Is there any reasonable way to determine if a file can be successfully deleted on the Windows platform using the go language?
I've tried using various flags calling os.OpenFile including using os.O_TRUNC all the calls are successful yet remove will fail when the file is in use.
I've also tried using the locking mechanisms specific to Windows (i.e. kern.NewProc("LockFileEx") etc) and these seem to get exclusive locks successfully yet os.Remove (after unlocking) will fail.
I realize that if between the test and the remove call if another process opens the file delete will still fail but this isn't the case here, with my tests I know the file is in use yet I can't find a test to tell me that (other than actually calling os.Remove)

Comment: A small hack could be to try renaming the file to itself, if it's successful then you should be able to delete it. You might also look into the `CreateFile` function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Open a handle with `DELETE` access and `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` share mode. Success means deleting should work, except for a read-only or memory-mapped file. In Vista+, you can use the handle to set the delete disposition via `SetFileInformationByHandle`. If it succeeds, the file is 'deleted' and cannot be reopened, but it's not unlinked. A file is unlinked only if its delete disposition is set when all handles for all referencing kernel File objects have been closed. Use your handle to unset the delete disposition if you don't really want to delete the file. Normal access will be restored.

Comment: Also, `LockFileEx` is for fine-grained control of shared read and write access (i.e. more than just an all-or-nothing). It's irrelevant to shared delete access. There's no possibility for fine-grained deleting of a file. You either share delete access or not. If you've shared delete access, then an exclusive lock on a range of the file does not prevent deleting the file.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, the Go [os.Remove](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Remove) function uses the Windows [DeleteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915.aspx) function. You must satisfy certain conditions for a Windows file to be deleted. For example, "The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed",  "The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that has other handles open for normal I/O", and so on.